# removing specific library from app build in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using storybook library in my react native application but only for development proposes
I would like to delete the bundle completely in production from the build folder

my package.json
this is how my devDependencies look like

```
  "devDependencies": {
    .....
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.14",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.14",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.14",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.14",
    "@storybook/react-native-server": "^5.3.14",
......}
```

and this is in the script

```
"scripts": {
  ....
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007",
....

}
```

any ideas how to do that ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and set up environment variables. You will be able to tell your app what to include in the local build, what to take for the development build and the production build.

The idea of such a configuration is not specific to React Native. It's part of an ideology of the best approach to write software, called the [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config)

This [article](https://dev.to/calintamas/how-to-manage-staging-and-production-environments-in-a-react-native-app-4naa) has a great detailed explanation on setting such variables using the [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

Comment: but that still doesn't answer my question on how we actually define what is taken to the development and what is to production, my question is about the step after having environments what is the way to restrain some parts of your code or some library from going to production

Comment: also for setting up Environments i found a very easy and library free way to do so 

https://itnext.io/the-easiest-way-to-setup-multiple-environments-on-react-native-67b33d073390